# Difference between sibling namespaces in nested vs global context

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have some C++ libraries that are written using nested namespaces. These libraries use many mathematical functions that, for readability, are better off read without explicitly specifying namespaces. Right now, a simplified version of the code would look like this.

```
namespace Base::Sibling1 {
  float cos(float x) { return cosf(x); }
};

namespace Base::Sibling2 {
  using namespace Sibling1;
  float f(float x) { return cos(x); }
};
```

We wanted to move to use flatter namespaces mostly to make it easier to extend the library with sibling code. We had hoped that a simple change like this would work:

```
namespace Sibling1 {
  float cos(float x) { return cosf(x); }
};

namespace Sibling2 {
  using namespace Sibling1;
  float f(float x) { return cos(x); }
};
```

Instead this fails now since `Sibling2::f()` calls `cos(x)` that is now ambiguous.

I have two questions

1. why is it ambiguous now and not int the first version?
2. is it possible to obtain the behavior we had before *without* listing all functions explicitly using `using Sibling1::cos`?

Comment: I'd personally remove `using namespace Sibling1;` and explicitly call `Sibling1::cos`.

Comment: I'm only able to reproduce your error with GCC. Clang and MSVC accept your second snippet. Might just be a bug. Edit: Clang 10 rejects it as well. Interesting.

Comment: If you have two `using` directives - i.e. `using namespace std` and `using namespace Sibling1` and `<cmath>` is included,  then `std::cos()` and `Sibling1::cos()` are both equally viable candidates for the `return cos(x)` - hence ambiguity. The only ways to avoid that if you want `Sibling2::f()` to call `Sibling1::cos()` are to remove the `using namespace std` or to explicitly name the function you intend (i.e. `return Sibling1::cos()`). Once a using directive is used, its effects cannot be undone in that compilation unit (i.e. there is nothing akin to `cancel_previous_using namespace std`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem cannot be reproduced as you describe it. Moreover, there is no reason that the flattening alone introduces ambiguities, if you use expose in the siblings the same names you introduced in `Base`.  So, the root cause is probably in some parts of the code you are not showing.

The second version does not define `cosf()`, so you probably are using some namespace.  If in that namespae there is also a `cos()` you create an ambiguity between the two overloads.  I could reproduce this by using namespace `std`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
namespace Sibling1 {
  float cos(float x) { return cosf(x); }
}
namespace Sibling2 {
  using namespace Sibling1;
  float f(float x) { return cos(x); }
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/r9JPwA): the compilation error indicates which are the candidates behind the ambiguity.  If you now comment the `using namespace` out, the ambiguity goes away, and the code compiles.  [Online proof](https://ideone.com/QUWFOu).

Namespaces are meant to avoid naming conflicts and keep control of  ambiguities:

- Creating a namespace and systematically `using namespace` everywhere defeats the whole purpose.
- On the other side, long `using` lists are painful to maintain, especially if you have to repeat them in several sibling namespaces.  This is probably why the `Base` and the nesting were created in the first place.

In the first version, you do not show what's in `Base`.  It is possible that some more tailored `using` clauses are used therein instead of full namespaces: if selectively injecting the really required functions in the `Base` namespace, they are made available within the siblings avoiding ambiguity that can be introduced by injecting the name of unnecessary functions.

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity is due to how using directives work.

> **[namespace.udir]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [2](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir#2) A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated
>   namespace can be used in the scope in which the using-directive
>   appears after the using-directive. **During unqualified name lookup
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual]), the names appear as if they were declared in
>   the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the
>   using-directive and the nominated namespace**. [ Note: In this context,
>   “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”. — end note ]
>
> [3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir#3) A using-directive does not add any members to the declarative
>   region in which it appears. [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace A {
>   int i;
>   namespace B {
>     namespace C {
>       int i;
>     }
>     using namespace A::B::C;
>     void f1() {
>       i = 5;        // OK, C​::​i visible in B and hides A​::​i
>     }
>   }
>   namespace D {
>     using namespace B;
>     using namespace C;
>     void f2() {
>       i = 5;        // ambiguous, B​::​C​::​i or A​::​i?
>     }
>   }
>   void f3() {
>     i = 5;          // uses A​::​i
>   }
> }
> void f4() {
>   i = 5;            // error: neither i is visible
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

So given your structure of namespaces, according to bit I made bold in paragraph 2, when you write

```
using namespace Sibling1;
```

It kinda translates to this

```
namespace /* Enclosing */ {

    using Sibling1::cos;

    namespace Sibling2 {
      float f(float x) { return cos(x); }
    };

}
```

The namespace I marked as enclosing is either `Base` or the global namespace. The "kinda" bit (according to paragraph 3) is that it's not an actual declaration being added. I.e. if something named `cos` already exists in `/* Enclosing */`, it's not a re-declaration. This is by design, because using directives can potentially bring a lot of names in, and so it shouldn't cause an error when the names they bring are not actually used.

In your case however, the name brought in *is* used.

When `/* Enclosing */` is `Base`, it matches only one declaration, the one in `Sibling1`, as-if it was declared in `Base`.

When `/* Enclosing */` is the global namespace, it matches the actual declaration there too, presumably the one brought in by `math.h` (you seem to be using that). So you get an ambiguity (the name refers to two potential entities).

So on the whole, compilers that reject this code are behaving as expected. While I understand your plight, I don't think there's really a problem for you to solve here. If client code finds `Base::Sibling1::cos` too verbose, it itself can employ a using directive of the form `using namespace Base;`. Or using a namespace alias to shorten things `namespace sib1 = Base::Sibling1;`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.